# how to estimate the number of convex region of a function numerically?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation

A convex region is where the second derivative of a function keeps the same sign.

Consider the function
$$
 f(x) = sin(x), x \in [0, 2\pi],
$$

what are the avalaible algorithm to estimate the number of convex region numerically?

Of course, the convex region are $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi, 2\pi]$, because
$$
 f''(x) = -sin(x).
$$
But, if the function was a black-box, numerical investigation would be the only resort.

Comment: That's not the usual meaning of "inflection point". Anyway, such a point is an extremum by default, so you're talking about optimization problems where you have bad regularity. There are numerous optimization methods that can deal with this bad regularity.

Comment: If the function was a  black box, then finding even continuity would require a numerical investigation, so too maxima minima etc. knowing the function, certain investigations happen far more smoothly. In your question, inflection point is not defined correctly, it is defined as:*A differentiable function has an inflection point at $(x, f(x))$ if and only if its first derivative, $f′$, has an isolated extremum at $x$.* Now, $|x|$ is not even differentiable at $0$, so you can't talk about $0$ being an inflection point of $x$. $|x|$ has no inflection points, for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Is your function at least continuous?  Is your function convex? Does it have any other special properties?

Comment: My bad, I'm not really interested in the exact location of the extremum of the function. I will edit the quesiton. What I would like is to have an idea of how many times the derivative change sign.